# maximum value of a tree scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to get the maximum value of a tree

I have this:

```
define (dato-tree nodo)
(first nodo))

(define (left-tree nodo)
 (first (rest nodo)))

(define (right-tree nodo)
 (first (rest (rest nodo))))

(define maximum
    (lambda (arbol) 
        (if (eqv? (right-tree arbol) #f)
            arbol
            (maximum (right-tree arbol)))))
```

and run it:

```
(define tree (list 5 (list 2 (list 1 empty empty) empty) (list 7 empty empty)))

(maximum tree)
```

gives me this error:

```
rest: expects a non-empty list; given: empty
```

how could it?

Comment: Are you running this in Dr.Racket?  Usually when there's an error, it will highlight the location in the code where the error occurred.  In this case, it'c clear that it's a use of `rest`, which you have in three places.  You should be able to trace the execution of your program and see where `(rest empty)` could be called.

Comment: Also, you've got a check `(eqv? (right-tree arbol) #f)` in your procedure, but there's no `#f` anywhere in your tree. When do you expect that test to succeed?  If it never succeeds, then you keep calling `(maximum (right-tree arbol))`, but the tree can't go on forever.  It's not too hard to see why you eventually call `(rest empty)`, then, is it?

Comment: yes, I understand how it could look then the maximum value of the tree?

Comment: I think that's the sort of question that might be answered by a data structures textbook or class.  Without worrying about the implementation side of it,  if a tree has three parts (the element, the left-subtree, and the right-subtree), then how can you define the maximum element of the whole tree?  treeMax(tree(element,left,right)) = max(element,treeMax(left),treeMax(right)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tree is a **sorted** binary tree as suggested in your previous question, you only have to consider the right branches and find the value of the last node:

```
(define (maximum arbol (m #f))
  (if (empty? arbol)
      m
      (maximum (right-tree arbol) (dato-tree arbol))))
```

then

```
> (maximum tree)
7
```

and you can even specify the value you want to be returned for an empty tree:

```
> (maximum empty)
#f
> (maximum empty 'empty)
'empty
> (maximum empty empty)
'()
```

**Otherwise** I would go for:

```
(define (cons2 atom lst) 
  (if atom (cons atom lst) lst))

(define (maximum arbol)
  (if (empty? arbol)
      #f
      (apply max 
             (cons2 (maximum (left-tree arbol))
                    (cons2 (maximum (right-tree arbol))
                           (list (dato-tree arbol)))))))
```

where `cons2` is a procedure that conses the atom only if it is not `#f`:

```
> (cons2 1 '(2))
'(1 2)
> (cons2 #f '(2))
'(2)
```

and comes in handy in procedure `maximum`to prevent testing if the maximum for a sub-tree is `empty`:

```
> (maximum tree)
7
> (maximum empty)
#f
```

Comment: @uselpa I believe this question is a follow-up to OP's previous question. If that's the case in a BST the maximum value is the right-most element, there's no need to traverse the whole tree and anyway a `max-value` procedure for trees (even unsorted) can be written that doesn't require intermediate lists.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez You may be right, but then I would have expected this important detail to appear in the question. Anyway, added this to my answer, thanks.